Why does the weight of $\text{gcd}(p(x),x^n-1)$ divide the weight of $p(x)\in\mathbb{F}_2[x]/\langle x^n-1\rangle$?
I noticed when playing around with $\mathbb{F}_2$-polynomials that the weight (number of non-zero terms) of $\text{gcd}(p(x),x^n-1)$, for any $p(x)\in\mathbb{F}_2[x]/\langle x^n-1\rangle$, always divides the weight of $p(x)$. I am not sure if this is a known result, but I'd be interested to see why this occurs.
All I got was the following: if $\text{deg}\;p(x) < d$, then any degree-$d$ cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi(x)\mid x^n-1$ trivially can not be a divisor of $p(x)$. Additionally, if the weight of $p(x)$ is 2, then either $p(x) \;|\; x^n-1$ or $\text{gcd} = 1+x$, so that the weight of the gcd is always 2, but that is about as far as I got.
EDIT: It was pointed out to me in the comments that my claim is not true, and only for a select number of cases does this divisibility identity manifest.

Interesting question.  I believe your claim about $p(x)$ with weight $2$ (i.e. either $p(x) \mid x^n - 1$ or $\gcd = 1+x$) isn't quite right as stated:  for example, $\gcd(x^6-1, x^4-1) = x^2-1$.  What is true is that if $p(x) = x^a + x^b = x^a - x^b$, then $\gcd(p(x), x^n-1) = \gcd(x^{a-b}-1, x^n-1) = x^{\gcd(a-b,n)}-1$.  This still has weight $2$, so your overall claim remains intact.

By the way, how strong is your evidence for this claim?  There are some famous patterns involving cyclotomic polynomials that break down only for relatively large $n$ (for example, the first cyclotomic polynomial with a coefficient $\notin {0, 1, -1}$ is $\Phi_{105}(x)$), so if you only have computational evidence then I for one would keep an open mind.

My gut reaction was that this cannot be true. But it obviously holds whenever $p(x)$ is irreducible, or a square of one. And for some other classes of polynomials. I guess the evidence your quest unearthed is a case of the law of small numbers.

If, for example, $p(x)=(1+x)q(x)$, where $q(x)$ is irreducible of degree $>1$, then, for all $n$, we have either $\gcd(x^n-1,p(x))=p(x)$ or $\gcd(x^n-1,p(x))=1+x$. All according to whether the zeros of $q(x)$ are roots of order $d\mid n$ or not. But in this case $p(x)$ always has an even weight (because $1$ is its zero), implying the claim in this case.

The elements of $F_2[x]/(x^n-1)$ are cosets of $(x^n-1)$, not polynomials, so the weight of $p(x)$ is not well-defined.

@JyrkiLahtonen My bad! I added the tag for clarity :-)

Not true, but I had to look for a bit higher degree polynomials to find counterexamples. So it is understandable to think the claim might be true. Consider the following.
If
$$p(x)=(1+x+x^2)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)=1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^6,$$
and $n=9$, then
$$(1-x^9)=(1-x^3)(1+x^3+x^6)=(1+x)(1+x+x^2)(1+x^3+x^6)$$
is a factorization into irreducibles of $\Bbb{F}_2[x]$. So
$$
\gcd(p(x),x^9-1)=1+x+x^2
$$
has weight three, but $p(x)$ itself has weight five.

See my comments under main for cues as to how I found this counterexample.

I see, it was merely a hypothesis based on a select number of examples I worked through, and it piqued my interest. Though maybe a more elementary question: the weight of $\text{gcd}$ does not divide the weight of $p(x)$ but it does seem to be always equal to or less than the weight of $p(x)$. Is this true, and if so, why? BTW, thank you sincerely for all your effort!

Never mind, I found a counterexample for this: $1+x+x^3+x^4+x^5 \mid 1+x^{17}+x^{27}; 1+x^{31}$
